# Is it possible to read or write steps in Watchkit extension?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit

I have read documents that said : All the data Apple Watch collects about your heart rate is then transferred automatically to the Health app on your iPhone. I have not found any Information about steps and calories. Whether it store in apple watch local storage or in Health App. If anyone knows about it then guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible to read or write steps data from a WatchKit extension. Extensions do not have HealthKit access. However, you could hand off to your iPhone app using `openParentApplication:reply:` and grab the data from the host app directly. It worth noting, however, that HealthKit data isn't necessarily delivered to the phone in real time.

Comment: Are Steps and Calories write in Health App like heart rate when Watch connect with iPhone?